# 24 pin potentiometer/rotary encoder identification

Tags: identification, potentiometer, rotary-encoder

I am building my first button box.  I got some electronic parts that were going to be scrapped to take some switches off.

I found this potentiometer or rotary encoder on one of them but I can't identify what it is. The words ALPS, Japan and 126p are printed on the side. It has 24 pins and snaps to the next position every time you turn the shaft. Any help in identifying the part would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Alps is the manufacturer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the absence of information from the manufacturer (Alps), the best you can do is to use a multimeter in the Ohms or continuity test mode and explore the connections between the pins. Try to identify the common connection first of all, then see how it is connected to the other pins as the switch is turned. You may find that the switch has multiple poles, each with a separate common connection.

Comment: Thanks, I will check it again with the multi-meter and see.

Answer (score 0):

it's probably a multi-pole switch - possilby 4P5T or 3P7T

eg source selector in stereo mixer.

> RADIO-GRAM-CD-LINE-TAPE1-TAPE2-MIC

oops that's 8 delete one.